# users' consent for user requirement specification document

Tags: requirements

I'm working for a software development company. The question that I have is whether should we present a user requirements specifications document for the customer/s before we start developing the actual system from scratch?

Comment: That rather depends on whether or not the project needs a User Requirements Specification.  Or even whether or not you currently have a customer.

Comment: I'm rather afraid that this is not just a matter of opinion, but even a basic principle at stake in what is effectively a religious war: Agile methods will day "no" (the customer should always be free to change their mind as the project continues and requiring sign off on requirements would either discourage or prevent that) while "traditional" methods say "yes" (having agreement to the specification is critical in preventing misunderstandings that could cause large amounts of wasted effort if uncovered late in the process). Neither is "right" per se, and depends on circumstance.

Comment: I have, therefore voted to close this question as "primarily opinion based", and suggest that reading up on the differences between z agile and traditional methods may allow you to find the answer for the particular projects you're working on.

Comment: @Jules Except the Agile methods say yes, just like the traditional methods. What is different is what "sign off" looks like. In agile, your stakeholders agree to the prioritization of the backlog. How is that different than agreeing to an initial Software Requirements Specification? It's not.

Comment: @ThomasOwens the critical difference is that a requirements specification makes a declaration about how the entire project is expected to go, whereas the prioritisation process of at least every agile method I've used is quite clear that only the near future of the project is being agreed to.

Comment: @Jules I've worked in projects where the requirements specification was a living document that grew through phases. It was not the entire project, but a fairly large chunk (much larger than one or two iterations in a typical agile project).

Answer (score 2):

Yes - it's important to have sign-off of requirements before you begin intensive development of a project.

Sign-off is a milestone in the project. [According to Karl Wiegers and Joy Beatty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735679665), it is the point at which the customers agree that the requirements meet their needs, the development team understands the requirements and agrees that they are feasible for implementation, the test team agrees that the requirements can be verified, and management agrees that the requirements allow for the business objectives to be achieved. It needs to be treated as an agreement, and not just a ritual to be followed.

From this point on, I'm not going to use the term "sign-off". I'm going to use "agreed upon". That is, the requirements are not "signed off", but "agreed upon" by representatives of the stakeholders.

Having an initial set of agreed upon requirements is essential. However, this should be treated as a requirements baseline. It's simply well known that, over time, requirements will change. Even if you are using a sequential methodology that calls for all of the requirements development to be done up-front, you need to recognize that the requirements are going to change. The agile methods are built around adapting to change in the environment, such as requirements changes.

In the agile methods, whoever is in the role similar to the Product Owner is the representative of the customer and users. Rather than agreeing upon the requirements once and modifying a baseline, your prioritized backlog of work is your baseline and you continually refine and prioritize it. You recognize up-front that refinement and re-prioritization is going to happen and your process allows for it to happen.

In my first sentence, I did use the phrase "intensive development". If you are in a contract-based environment, you may not have funding or staffing allocated for detailed requirements elicitation and analysis before you have a signed contract. As such, some design work may need to begin based on the initial requirements at the same time that the requirements are being developed to ensure that you can complete the work in the allotted schedule. You may also need to use this time to procure physical resources, set up environments, and do prototyping.

Do note that prototyping is a valid requirements elicitation technique, so this early setup work and prototyping done by the development team can feed into the requirements development process and also serve as a check on the work done to try to minimize risk of doing the wrong thing.